# Can the -ㅁ nominalizer ending be attached to all 용언?

Tags: grammar, verb-endings

As far as I understand, the -ㅁ ending can be added to a verb to make a noun representing a ‘completed’ or ‘embodied’ action. for example:

> 말하다 means to speak, 말씀 means speech.
>
> 만나다 means to meet; 만남 is a meeting.
>
> 죽다 is to die; 죽음 is death.

Can -ㅁ be added to descriptive verbs as well, like 예쁘다 → 예쁨? would that mean something like 'prettiness' or beauty? what about 크다 → 큼, meaning 'bigness' or 'having a large size'?

Finally, what about the copula, 이다, and its negative 아니다? can 'ㅁ' be attached to make '임' and '아님'? If so, how could those be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, virtually all verbs/adjectives, and also 이다 and 아니다, allow -ㅁ, but not all of them are a noun in its own right.

The situation is similar to English -ing: some -ing forms are separate words (a long *meeting* / a bad *feeling*) but many are merely "noun-forms" of the corresponding verb and do not act as a separate word.  E.g., ***Arriving** at 5 will be difficult.*, but usually not *The train's **arriving** was late.*  Instead, we say *The train's **arrival** was late.*

Similarly, many words with -ㅁ can be used to build a clause that acts like a noun phrase, but they aren't separate words.  Some random examples from the web:

> 앞길이 매우 멀고도 **큼**을 일컫는 고사성어
>
> 경찰 출두 시민들 "촛불이 무죄**임**을 밝혀내겠다"
>
> 정식 출시 **아님**에도 불구하고 '포켓몬GO' 구글플레이 게임부문 '4위'

- However, one might consider 예쁨 as a separate noun inside the idiom 예쁨을 받다, which means *to be favored* (=~ 귀여움을 받다).

Answer (score 2):

There is a writing style called 개조식(個條式) that uses -ㅁ copula. Example of a 개조식 article:

1. 주요 특징

   - 말머리표 또는 번호로 구분됨.
   - 서술이 길어지는 문장을 지양하고 요점만 기재함.
   - 문장이 계층화되어 있음.
2. 일반적 문법 주의사항 (국립국어원의 답변 종합)

   - 개조식의 각 문장이 완성되지 않은 경우 끝에 마침표를 찍어서는 안 됨.

     - "~OOO 등" 과 같이 끝나는 문장 등
   - 그러나 동사의 명사형(OO함 등)으로 끝난 경우 마침표가 필요함.

     - 문장이 완성된 것으로 간주, 구두점이 요구됨.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes.  That doesn't mean you will see them all, but I have seen 예쁨 and forms ending with 임 and 아님 and many others.

The thing to understand is that nouns made this way have a different nuance than nouns made with 기 or nouns made with (으)ㄴ/는 것...  ㅁ-ending nouns are said to indicate static, well-established, extant states and/or abstract, timeless truths.  They are found more often with DVs than with AVs.

I don't see how the above responder can say they aren't nouns.  If you add (으)ㅁ to a verb root, you create a noun, except in the case of a sentence-ending form which is a different case.