# Is there a word that describes 'words that verb endings can attach to' - i.e. 동사, 형용사, 이다?

Tags: vocabulary

A question that occurred to me while asking [this](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/can-the-%e3%85%81-nominalizer-ending-be-attached-to-all-verbs-and-adjectives-what-abou) one...

동사 (action verbs), 형용사 (adjectives or descriptive verbs), and 이다 (the 'copula') all broadly accept  'verb endings', e.g.

> 가다 : 갑니다
>
> 예쁘다 : 예쁩니다
>
> 이다: 입니다

Is there a word (Korean or English) to collectively describe 'words that you can add verb endings on to'? Maybe I mean something like 'conjugatable'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the word "용언" is used to mean words that can be followed by verb / adjective endings (which are called 어미 in Korean); the opposite is "체언", for words that cannot be followed by 어미.

용언 include verbs (동사), adjectives (형용사) and the copula (sometimes called 지정사; this includes both the [clitic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic) -이다 and the word 아니다).